# Should we burninate the jailbreak tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Got a bit surprised by finding the [jailbreak](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jailbreak), that by definition:

> process of removing the limitations imposed by Apple on devices running the iOS operating system through the use of hardware/software exploits...

<sup>See the Wikipedia article regarding [jailbreaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking)</sup>

While a jargon expression, it is strictly associated with iOS devices. For Android devices, the jargon is ["Rooting"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29).

This terms exist and essentially mean the same thing, but each one is specific to a different device type using a different software. At Android Enthusiasts, we deal with only one type, Android, but yet we have three questions sitting on the main site since 2010 tagged [jailbreak](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jailbreak):

- [Is it possible to completely brick your Android phone by using a Custom ROM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/876/16265)
- [(how) can I install android on an iphone 4? [closed]](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/847/16265)
- [What is the difference between jailbreaking and unlocking an Android? [closed]](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/801/16265)

<sup>*Two of the three questions already have [rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting)*</sup>

While two of the three questions are closed, one remains open and the tag remains active. Whether the questions are useful or not, that's another topic, what I'm discussing is:

Is it good to have a tag that's specificity directed to a non-android device? If not, should it be **burninate** and/or **blacklisted**, or by popular demand, merge and create a synonym?

Comment: Burnination seems like overkill for a tag that's only on three questions. Best to just remove it from those questions and let the tag auto-delete. If it keeps coming back we can reconsider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest simply making the [jailbreak](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jailbreak) a synonym of [rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rooting). This way users who try to use the tag are automatically pointed to the right term/tag.

Comment: Didn't think of this at first, makes sense, tks.

Answer (score 3):

I merged the tag `jailbreak` to `rooting` and created a synonym.

Comment: Nice, seems to be the popular demand. I've updated the question, as to better allow a "status-completed".

Comment: Did you forget the status-completed tag?

Comment: @Flow whoops, thanks, forgot to add it. Tag added